# The dom element in context of view from the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I have a form in a angular view. And in the button on the form, I've added an event to send request to the server using $http. Before sending the request to the server, I need to validate the form using jQuery Validate.

To validate the form, I need the dom reference of the form in the controller. I already have jQuery in my application. So can get the reference of the form using

```
$(selecter) or angular.element($(selecter))
```

But in both cases, it'll search the full document to get the reference of the element. Instead of that I need to search the element within the context of the view, which will increase the performance.

I've seen the use of $element in angular. But later I've seen that the use of $element is not recommended and it may be depreciated in the new version of angular. And when I'm trying to get $element within the controller, I'm getting an error. So I guess it's depreciated already.

So what is the best way to get dom element in context of view from the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as Mikalai said. To manipulate with any element you have to create directive(this is angular way..)

For an example:

- html `<input type="text" select-all value="test" />`
- directive

  ```
  app.directive('selectAll', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('click', function() {
              this.select();
          });
      };
  });
  ```

This directive just select all text in text element.

**UPDATE:**

I've created [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BaIsIfZCsjbqyaVAsIO5) for you. Is this what you're asking for?

**UPDATE 2**

I just realized, that we don't need eval here at all. I don't know, why I put it there in the first place. Eval could also be harmful.

Look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VcvkxVQBUYhb1npdN66o).

Comment: In that case, for each form in my application, I've to create a new directive. So it'll better if I can do this using controller.

Comment: Or you can declare function's in controller, then just pass their names in directive thrugh attrs and in directive use eval('var fn = + 'attrs.function) to use them? I dunno, just thinking :)

Comment: Actually I'm new in angular js, can you please add some code in plunkr or jsfiddle.

Comment: Check my answer again. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

To work with dom elements in context of view from the controller is not recommended. For accessing dom you should create angular directives.