# Form validation Not working with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms

I've a form inside table.

```
    <table class='table table-bordered'>
        <caption>ADD NEW BRAND</caption>

        <tbody>
            <form ng-app="" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="myForm">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <TR>
                        <TD>Brand Name</TD>

                        <TD>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="newbrand.Name" placeholder="Enter Brand Name" required>
                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.name.$dirty && myForm.name.$invalid">
                                <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required">Brand Name is required.</span>
                            </span>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                </div>
            </form>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When input field is empty, it should give a indication that Brand Name is required. But its not working.

Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using directive:-
For an example:

```
html

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form novalidate class="person" name="personForm" test-directive validation="submitPerson" ng-submit="submitForm(personForm)">
      <h3>Person form</h3>
      <input type="text" required name="first-name" ng-model="person.firstName" ng-class="{'valid':personValid}" />
      <input type="submit" value="post" />
    </form>
  </body>
```

Controller & Directive

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.person = {
    firstName: 'Clem'
  };


  $scope.submitPerson = function(form, element) {
    console.log("Person validation here!")
    if(form.$valid) {
      $scope.personValid = true;
    }
    else {
      $scope.personValid = false;
    }
  };

});

app.directive('testDirective', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.submitForm = function(form) {
        eval("var fn = scope." + attrs.validation);
        fn(form, ele);
      }
    }
  };
})
```

Credit :- [Form validation in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295740/the-dom-element-in-context-of-view-from-the-controller/27296155?noredirect=1#comment43063810_27296155)